# Using a web site button control via C/++

Tags: c++, windows, google-chrome, web

I use www.jango.com as PC music player and want to steer it remotly via my smartphone. I have a server program for controling the PC and an app as client.
I want to use the server program for example to press the play/pause or fast forward button in jango.com running inside the chrome webbrowser.

A simple way would be to simulate a windows mouse click at a specified position within the chrome window. But it would have the disadvantage that it would only work if the jango tab is active and will of course fail if the site changes it's layout and probably due to a lot other reasons.

So I'm thinking about generating kind of the same http request as the browser does if one clicks the button for real. Or somehow accessing the html elemnt

Please consider thatm while having a C/++ background, I lack any web/JS programming skills and would be in favor keeping it this way as much as possible.

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: `I lack any web/JS programming skills` Maybe you should learn some?

Comment: I suggest you using the `mechanize` python library.

Comment: sounds like a job for AutoIt

Comment: According to wikipedia, Autoit does support only IE and not chrome

Comment: And how would my C++ server interface mechanize @Andre?

Comment: @beutelfuchs actually I was suggesting that you use only python... But if you really need to interface C++ and Python I Boost.python is amazing!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use an user script for the musik player web site which is able to trigger the buttons in question. Than websockets can be used to communicate between the user script and the c++ server program.